# Firmware Bug in Linux Ubuntu 17.10 running on VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, 17.10, macosx, firmware

I recently installed the latest version of Ubuntu (version 17.10 Artful Aardvark) on Mac OSx (High Sierra version 10.13.1).

Everything went fine and Ubuntu works perfectly except for the video that the video that becomes black for 1 second when you try to run a program/software.

I link such problem to the firmware bug that Ubuntu reports during the Boot phase; The error message is the following:

```
[Firmware Bug] TSC-deadline disabled due to errata: please update microcode to version: 0x25 (or later)
```

Any idea/advice to solve such problem?

Any help would be appreciated!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: 16.04 and 18.04 are LTS, 17.10 is not. You should install intel-microcode on the host.

Comment: Ok, you're right @N0rbert. I will try to install again the distribution. Thanks for the comment!

Comment: If you do not need LTS status, you may continue to use installed one.

Comment: I don't need of it, but it could solve the problem of the firmware. @N0rbert